# What does a time limit with a dash like -t 10-0 in SLURM mean?

Tags: slurm

I have just seen

```
sbatch [many options] -t 10-0 [more options + bash script]
```

I've found in the help

```
  -t, --time=minutes          time limit
```

so `-t` definitely is a time limit. But is `10-0` 10 minutes and 0 seconds? Or 10 hours 0 minutes? Or even something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means 10 days. The general format is `d-hh:mm:ss` though the scheduler will most probably not honour the `ss` part.

Note that Slurm can be configured to offer a grace period after the requested time is elapsed. See the `OverTimeLimit` parameter in `scontrol show config`

Answer (score 1):

I've just found it in the `man` pages:

```
-t, --time=<time>
      Set  a  limit on the total run time of the job allocation.  If the requested time limit exceeds the partition's time limit, the job
      will be left in a PENDING state (possibly indefinitely).  The default time limit is the partition's  time  limit.   When  the  time
      limit is reached, each task in each job step is sent SIGTERM followed by SIGKILL.  The interval between signals is specified by the
      SLURM configuration parameter KillWait.  A time limit of zero requests that no time limit  be  imposed.   Acceptable  time  formats
      include "minutes", "minutes:seconds", "hours:minutes:seconds", "days-hours", "days-hours:minutes" and "days-hours:minutes:seconds".
```